# Run service with previledges of another user?

Tags: server, security, 15.10, couchdb

I want to host a CouchDB but heard that it might be wise not to run it as a root but create an own user for that with little privileges as possible.

How can I achieve that? When I just install CouchDB it seems like it gets started as a service with the root privileges.

Comment: How do you know that it started as root user?

Comment: I assumed it. How can I check it?

Comment: Why did you assume? That is not the way to check it but I'd try `id couchdb` and if this user exsists I'd assume it is started as user couchdb.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
runuser -l  userNameHere -c 'command'
```

This will ...  **;-)**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you explain a bit more instead of just posting the command?  And also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo -u youruser command` to run something as another user. The main difference to `runuser` ist that you can run `sudo` as a Sudoer but you can only run `runuser` as root.

And since we don't have a root password by default on Ubuntu you would run `sudo -u user command` instead of `sudo runuser`.

Comment: I only have a root user by default. I am using Ubuntu Server version. CouchDB starts itself as a service, so I am not sure how I can apply your suggested solution.

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek Oh yeah I see, I over read the server tag. I have no idea what CouchDB is but if you installed it via `apt-get` or `aptitude` it should have created a CouchDB user or so.